# SQL LEFT OUTER JOIN not working

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

```
SELECT
   s.SeatNo, BOOKING_ID
FROM
   SEAT s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   BOOKING b ON (s.SeatNo = b.SeatNo) AND (plane_id = 'BEY101');
```

I have 5 planes and 150 seats for each plane. I want to show all seats (150) for the flight and the number of seats booked (let say 50) (i.e. 150 in the result set's first column and 50 in its second column).

Comment: How is it not working?  And what table is `plane_id` in?  And can you show sample output?

Comment: i think is the (plane_id='BEY101') condition not working as the result shown all seats from the 5 planes(750 records ) but i only want to have the first plane in the result (150)

Comment: You don't want the plane id in the join condition, you want it in a where clause.

Answer (score 2):

Your query seems very close to what you are asking for.  I can think of one thing that would be wrong.  That is if `plane_id` is in the `seat` table.  Perhaps this query will solve your problem:

```
select s.SeatNo, b.BOOKING_ID
from SEAT s LEFT OUTER JOIN
     BOOKING b
     ON s.SeatNo = b.SeatNo 
where s.plane_id = 'BEY101';
```

`Left outer join`s work in a very specific way.  Every row in the first table is in the result set, regardless of whether the `on` clause evaluates to true or false.  This even applies to conditions on the first table.  So, when doing a `left outer join`, an `on` condition on the first table has no effect.  Such conditions should be in the `where` clause.

Comment: Joins can be hard to wrap your head around, but this guide has always helped me, as OP seems confused about the differences. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins Makes it a little bit easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

please try below,may be missing b.BOOKING_ID,

```
select s.SeatNo,b.BOOKING_ID 
from SEAT s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN BOOKING b ON(s.SeatNO=b.SeatNO) and (plane_id='BEY101')
```